# Find a link attribute depending on an other attribute and the link value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some links looking this way:

```
<a href="..." data-pk="xxx" data-model="xxx">The link text</a>
```

And I'm trying to access using jquery the data-model value knowing the link text and the data-pk.

For now I can find the model depending on the PK

```
params.model = $("a[data-pk="+ params.pk + "]").attr("data-model");
```

But I would like to have a matching PK AND  link text. My link text is accessible in params.value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `:contains` pseudo-selector:

```
$("a[data-pk="+ params.pk + "]:contains(" + params.value + ")")
```

Comment: Thank u very much! I'm not an expert in jquery and I didn't know this selector!

Answer (score 0):

Use `:contains` in the selector:

```
params.model = $('a[data-pk=' + params.pk + ']:contains(' + params.value + ')').attr('data-model');
```

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qK9cc/) shows how it works.